# Bootstrap file input styler

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This simple JavaScript code styles all file inputs to match with Bootstrap's style.

Simply, it turns this:

[image: Unstyled input]

Into this input:

[image: Styled input]

---

```
(function(window){
    window.jQuery(function($){
        $('input[type="file"]').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var $parent = $this.parent();
            $this.detach();
            $parent.prepend(
                $('<div id="' + $this.attr('id') + '_input-group" class="input-group">' +
                    '<label class="input-group-btn" for="' + $this.attr('id') + '">' +
                        '<span class="btn">' + ($this.attr('data-label') || 'New image:') + '</span>' +
                    '</label>' +
                    '<input id="' + $this.attr('id') + '_path" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">' +
                    '<label class="input-group-btn" for="' + $this.attr('id') + '">' +
                        '<span class="btn btn-primary">' +
                            ($this.attr('data-button-label') || 'Browse') +
                            '<div style="display:none;"></div>' +
                        '</span>' +
                    '</label>' +
                '</div>')
            );

            $this.appendTo('#' + $this.attr('id') + '_input-group label:last-child div:last-child');

            var $path = $('#' + $this.attr('id') + '_path', $parent).click(function(){
                $this.click();
            });

            $this.bind('change.input_file_styler', function(){
                $path.val(this.files[0] ? this.files[0].name : '');
            });
        });
    });
})(Function('return this')());
```

I really can't put my finger on what's wrong... but I know that something is stinking in there!

What can I improve in this code?

---

If you want to try it out:

```js
(function(window){
 window.jQuery(function($){
  $('input[type="file"]').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var $parent = $this.parent();
   $this.detach();
   $parent.prepend(
    $('<div id="' + $this.attr('id') + '_input-group" class="input-group">' +
     '<label class="input-group-btn" for="' + $this.attr('id') + '">' +
      '<span class="btn">' + ($this.attr('data-label') || 'New image:') + '</span>' +
     '</label>' +
     '<input id="' + $this.attr('id') + '_path" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">' +
     '<label class="input-group-btn" for="' + $this.attr('id') + '">' +
      '<span class="btn btn-primary">' +
       ($this.attr('data-button-label') || 'Browse') +
       '<div style="display:none;"></div>' +
      '</span>' +
     '</label>' +
    '</div>')
   );
   
   $this.appendTo('#' + $this.attr('id') + '_input-group label:last-child div:last-child');
   
   var $path = $('#' + $this.attr('id') + '_path', $parent).click(function(){
    $this.click();
   });
   
   $this.bind('change.input_file_styler', function(){
    $path.val(this.files[0] ? this.files[0].name : '');
   });
  });
 });
})(Function('return this')());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<input type="file" id="file" data-label="Select file to upload:" data-button-label="...">
```

Answer (score 3):

### `Function('return this')()`

It took two minutes to me to understand what it does. Let's see what it does step by step

```
Function('return this')()
```

This is another way of creating function. An anonymous function which simply returns `this` object. `()` at the end of it will invoke this function immediately. This is equivalent to `window`. Why not just use `window` instead of writing this *mysterious* statement.

### Do we need IIFE?

IIFE is used to avoid polluting global scope. In the code, there is no code other than `window.jQuery(function($){` inside it. Thus, IIFE is not containing any variable or function that could be global. As variables/functions defined inside a function are not accessible from outside of it(provided variables are declared using `var` keyword), the callback function of `window.jQuery(function($){` serves as the container scope.

In simple words, IIFE can be removed safely.

### `jQuery(function($) {`

I, generally don't use the shorthand of `ready`. It looks confusing for readers who are not familiar with it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

is readable. jQuery, call the function when document is *ready*.

### `window.jQuery`

`window` here is not required as `jQuery` is global object and only `jQuery` will work. No harm in using `window` but using only `jQuery` will save some keystrokes.

If you're not using any other library like prototype.js, MooTools, YUI, etc. that also uses `$` namespace, you can use `$` instead of typing `jQuery`.

See [Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

### `:file` selector

You may use [`:file`](https://api.jquery.com/file-selector/) pseudo-selector to select `<input type="file" />` elements. This again, saves some keystrokes and is readable too.

```
$('input:file').each(function() {
```

### Caching `$this.attr('id')`

`$this.attr('id')` is used 6 times in the code. This can be cached just like you cached `$(this)` so that, jQuery don't have to read the attribute value again and again.

```
var id = $this.attr('id'); // Cached the ID of element
```

and use `id` in the code.

### `attr()` vs `data()`

To read the value of `data-*` attribute, jQuery has provided [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.
Instead of `$this.attr('data-button-label')`, `$this.data('buttonLabel')` can be used.

### `bind()`

[`bind()` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). To bind events us [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). `bind` internally calls `on`. By using `on()` directly, yo'll save one extra function call. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33654898/2025923) on StackOverflow.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  'use strict';

  $('input:file').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parent();
    var id = $this.attr('id');

    $this.detach();
    $parent.prepend(
      $('<div id="' + id + '_input-group" class="input-group">' +
        '<label class="input-group-btn" for="' + id + '">' +
        '<span class="btn">' + ($this.data('label') || 'New image:') + '</span>' +
        '</label>' +
        '<input id="' + id + '_path" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">' +
        '<label class="input-group-btn" for="' + id + '">' +
        '<span class="btn btn-primary">' +
        ($this.data('buttonLabel') || 'Browse') +
        '<div style="display:none;"></div>' +
        '</span>' +
        '</label>' +
        '</div>')
    );

    $this.appendTo('#' + id + '_input-group label:last-child div:last-child');

    var $path = $('#' + id + '_path', $parent).click(function() {
      $this.click();
    });

    $this.on('change.input_file_styler', function() {
      $path.val(this.files[0] ? this.files[0].name : '');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<input type="file" id="file" data-label="Select file to upload:" data-button-label="...">
```

Comment: You made good points, but you also some I really disagree. Using `Function('return this')()` is just an insane safeguard, in case the `window` object isn't the `window`. Also, `window.jQuery` and `jQuery`, inside that anonymous function, is **very** different. Outside, anything can happen, and the `window` variable can have/be anything. About using `:file`, I agree that it is readable but it is a performance nightmare. You can read about what happens on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101207/ (I describe what happens to pseudo-selectors, like `:file`). [...]

Comment: [...] You should read the "Additional Notes" section on the `:file` pseudo-selector. I **TOTALLY** agree with "caching" `$this.attr('id')`. I don't know how it escaped me. For that bit alone, you deserve an upvote. But then, I disagree about your `attr()` vs `data()`. The intention is to **only** use attributes. Using `data()` can hide the name of the attributes that you can use. This exposes another issue: no documentation. But using `attr()` doesn't seem an issue. Also, I had no idea that `bind()` is deprecated. That's entirelly new to me. I will replace it with `.on()`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel regarding the `window` safeguard, I don't think it is [required anymore](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/o7tucbcs/). For `window.jQuery` and `jQuery` will refer to same object as there is no local variable named `jQuery` in the IIFE. Only thing is that `jQuery` will require scope chaining till global object where it is defined. And as explained, IIFE can be removed here.

Comment: You're right, it isn't required anymore. Assuming your code is written into a single file and isn't minified and "mangled" with a load of other javascript files. (I think Wordpress does this, to reduce HTTP roundtrips). And those files are all wrapped in an `eval()` (not `window.eval()`!, that has a different scope) or a `Function()`. If one script has `var window = <stuff>;`, you broke the code. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/tznsa59s/

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I didn't consider minification process when writing the answer. Your both points are valid. The review stands for the given code. Also, minification is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: That's correct, but it is a given that **any** Javascript code will be minimified to reduce it's network fingerprint (in adition to gzipping). I'm in no way saying that your review is bad or wrong. It isn't. But, considering minification, my code isn't optimal. I've forgotten to add a single `;` before the code, just in case it gets all mangled. One this that escaped me is that the first parameter on the `load` event is an instance of jQuery. That is, `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ [...] });` allows me to use `$();` inside the code, even if someone runs `jQuery.noConflict()`.